# Reporting services code for condition parameter

Tags: sql-server-2005, reportingservices-2005

Is there any code for condition  parameter  to show the condition in text format by changing it from string format.  i want to display condition in text format. whenever i search something that should be shown under each page in text format.

Eg: If i search  1)Physician Name like `'%'` then it should be physician Name like `'ALL'`.

I dont want want any extra Parameters. I am using a Parameter called Condition in my report.
so whenever i searched with some condition it should be shown in text format in the bottom of each page.
now it's showing as it is what am giving.

Eg: contractname like '%' then its showing contractname like '%%%'
    contractname stats with P  its showing contractname like 'P%'   but i want it as contractname like 'P ' 
    (or) contractname starts with p.

Answer (score 0):

Given the parameter named "myParameter", you can reference the value in your report as
=Parameters!myParameter.Value